# Set Transparent Color for the Whole JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, transparent

I have a JPanel with a JLabel which owns an Icon picture.
how do I set a transparent red color at the top of the whole JPanel (including JLabel Icon)?
I have the transparent backgriound color on for the panel but I want the whole panel including the picture and everything get this transparent color. something like a transparent colorful glass at the top of the JPanel

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TransparentJLabel {
    private static final String IMAGE_PATH = "http://duke.kenai.com/Oracle/OracleStratSmall.png";

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.pink);

        URL imageUrl;
        try {
            imageUrl = new URL(IMAGE_PATH);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
            panel.add(label);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TransparentJLabel");
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Swing components are either fully transparent or fully opaque.  You can cheat by making the component fully transparent and overriding it's `paintComponent` method and filling the area of the component with what ever color your want

Comment: To do an overlay is much more complicated in this situation. You might consider using a JLayer/JXLayer. Otherwise you consider using an Overlay layout manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need a layered panel over the whole `contentPane`, a simple [`glassPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) will do fine (override it's `paintComponent(...)` method). For example:

```
JPanel glassPane = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setColor(new Color(0, 100, 0, 100));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2.dispose();
    }
};
glassPane.setOpaque(false);

frame.setGlassPane(glassPane);
frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
```

---

However, if you want a layered panel over only *one* `JPanel`, I would use `JLayer` combined with `LayerUI`, as MadProgrammer already mentioned. You will need a custom `LayerUI` in which you override the `paint(Graphics g, JComponent c)` method. I know that sounds dangerous, but I honestly don't know of another way of doing it...

I've provided an example below, this is the output:

[image]

As you can see, `panel1` (or more accurately, the `JLayer`) is slighty transparent (`RGBA = "0, 100, 0, 100"`) and `panel2` is normal.

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }

    public Example() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.add(new JButton("Panel 1"));
        MyLayerUI layerUI = new MyLayerUI();
        JLayer<JPanel> panel1Layer = new JLayer<JPanel>(panel1, layerUI);
        panel1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (layerUI.hasOverlay()) {
                    layerUI.setOverlay(false);
                } else {
                    layerUI.setOverlay(true);
                }
                panel1Layer.repaint();
            }
        });

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.add(new JButton("Panel 2"));

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        contentPane.add(panel1Layer);
        contentPane.add(panel2);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class MyLayerUI extends LayerUI<JPanel> {
    private boolean overlay = true;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        super.paint(g, c);
        if (hasOverlay()) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.setColor(new Color(0, 100, 0, 100));
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
            g2.dispose();
        }
    }

    public boolean hasOverlay() {
        return overlay;
    }

    public void setOverlay(boolean overlay) {
        this.overlay = overlay;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please mention how to remove the panel1Layer on click ? are you going to pass a default parameter to paint method or you replace the panel1Layer UI with new JPanel ?

Comment: @Mehdi Yes, I think a boolean indicating if the green area should be painted or not would be the best solution - I updated the code.

Comment: @Mehdi Wait... Do you mean to remove the whole `panel1Layer` including the button? If that is what you meant, check out [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).